# How do I get my very large Win32 Desktop App through login review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have a very large Win32 Desktop application (`Installer MSI > 100Mb + SQL2012_WT`) through the Facebook Login Review process.

We have a small part of the app which allows the user to view their feed and also create posts without the need to use a separate app or web browser.

So we need more than just the basic 3 permissions so the app needs to be reviewed, but the website only allows Websites or Mobile apps to be submitted.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements#platforms

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a technical/programming issue but Facebook app review process that is more suitable in the [Facebook developer group](https://facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers)